# Bound on moments of sub-Gaussian random variable

Tags: probability-theory

I want to show the following exercise:

> For a sub-Gaussian random variable $X$, one has $\mathbb{E}\left[ \lvert X \rvert^k \right] \leq (ck)^{k/2}$ for some constant $c > 0$ and all $k = 1, 2, 3, \dots$.

I tried using the *layer cake formula* and obtained

$$
\mathbb{E} \left[ \lvert X \rvert ^k  \right] = \int_0^\infty kt^{k-1} \mathbb{P} \left[ \lvert X \rvert > t \right] dt \leq \int_0^\infty kt^{k-1} Me^{-mt^2} dt
$$

for some constants $M, m > 0$. I tried to use partial integration from there, however it did not work out.

Comment: This might be useful ${\displaystyle \Gamma (z)=\int _{0}^{\infty }x^{z-1}e^{-x}\,dx}$, and $\Gamma(k) = k!$ for an integer $k$.

Comment: Are you sure the question is correct? I think the $k^{1/k}$ should be $k^{k/2}$

Comment: See prop 2.5.2 in https://www.math.uci.edu/~rvershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.pdf or or exercise 1.1.4 in https://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/matrix-book.pdf